# Automatically create label based on plus-address

Tags: google-apps-email

We are using shared Google Apps address to collect project-related email. Our convention is to use projects+code@our-domain.tld

At the moment, we can use the front-end of Gmail to search for project-related correspondence but I would like the correspondence to be automatically sorted into folders based on the + codes. We are using hierarchical approach, where the code consists of client id and sequential identifier.

Is there any way to avoid creation of labels + filter rules for every new project? Is there any more "advanced" view of gmail correspondence that could automate the above?

Comment: I assume you're familiar with https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ but I'm guessing what you want would require some work. You could use separate user accounts, but that doesn't really solve your problem, it just moves it to account space for address space.

Comment: thank you @barrycarter. I am looking first of all for an off-the-shelf solution, if that does not exist, I will start rolling something of my own but ideally would like to avoid it!

Comment: While this isn't an answer to your question, have you looked into using a Google Group configured as a collaborative inbox? This allows you to control who has access to the emails without the security risk of sharing an account's credentials or any dev time. Google Groups also don't require a separate Google Apps licence like an account does, so this option is also cheaper. https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Use the Gmail features related to search.

## Explanation

1. Create a contact by each project so you could use the automatically created links that will search for messages sent to each of your projects.
2. Create URLs / bookmarks for each of your projects. They will look like the following

   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/to:projects+code@our-domain.tld

Comment: This looks great! However, as I would ideally not like to give all of our users access to the email account, could this be implemented via an API? I am looking at minimising dev time while giving users the option to browse email comms. Simple text view + attachments will be sufficient for the messages.

Comment: That deserves it's own question :)